# WP REST API returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

An endpoint of `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/123` returns a combination of HTML and JSON format such as:

```
<div class="my-class">HTML Content</div>
{ "id" : 123, ... }
```

There is an excerpt filter in `functions.php` that set the outputted HTML, in this line:

```php
function my_custom_filter(){
  echo '<div class="my-class">HTML Content</div>';
}
add_filter ('the_excerpt', 'my_custom_filter' );
```

How to prevent such filter from intervening with the JSON response?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can modify the filter, then you can detect the REST API inside the filter function, like this:

```
function my_custom_filter(){
    if (! defined("REST_REQUEST")) {
        echo '<div class="my-class">HTML Content</div>';
   }
}
add_filter ('the_excerpt', 'my_custom_filter' );
```

The constant `REST_REQUEST` is only defined inside a request that was handled by the REST API. So, with the code above, if a request is being handled by the normal WP request cycle, the constant will not be defined, so the `if` statement we added will evaluate as `true` and the `echo` will occur like normal. If the constant **is** defined, then the `if` will evaluate as false and the filter will not add any output to the response.

See https://wpseek.com/constant/rest_request/

**UPDATE**: while the code above will work, I think we can do better.

The problem is that if you have many filters, every one of them needs to duplicate the `if` statement and your code become littered with checks for `REST_REQUEST`, which

- is repetitive (not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
- not the [concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of the filters themselves
- untidy

Instead, we can introduce the `REST_REQUEST` checks earlier in the cycle by making it a concern of the code that *adds the filter*.

This would look like:

```
function my_custom_filter(){
    echo '<div class="my-class">HTML Content</div>';
}

if (! defined("REST_REQUEST")) {
    add_filter ('the_excerpt', 'my_custom_filter' );
    //add other HTML filters here
} else {
    //attach REST API actions
}
```

This seems like a small change (if you catch it early, when the number of filters is small), but it potentially brings some big advantages:

- it keeps the `REST_REQUEST` checks all in one place: [maintainability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability)
- the filters don't need to know or care about whether it's a `REST_REQUEST` or not - if they get called, they're good to go. Keeping it simple.
- you can potentially do other things like logging or role-based access checks in that place: [extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility)

It's a relatively easy change to make early on in your application, but becomes more difficult and error prone as you add further filters and actions. Always better to do it right the first time!

Comment: Sorry for the edits to my answer! Hope it makes sense now. I was answering the question on mobile, with clumsy fingers :)

Comment: hi guys, i am new in wordpress. i want to get wordpress pages content into android app, so where will i have to put this code, thanks in advance for your valueable answer

Answer (score 2):

The real issue here is `echo`ing content during a filter, with the assumption it is being output to the same place `echo` would. One should only ever modify filtered content. To correct that code:

```php
function my_custom_filter($excerpt) {
  return '<div class="my-class">HTML Content</div>' . "\n$excerpt";
}
add_filter ('the_excerpt', 'my_custom_filter');
```

In this case, OP probably still wants the conditional:

```php
function my_custom_filter($excerpt) {
  return !defined('REST_REQUEST') || !REST_REQUEST ?
    '<div class="my-class">HTML Content</div>' . "\n$excerpt" :
    $excerpt;
}
add_filter ('the_excerpt', 'my_custom_filter');
```